# UITextField inputView appears dark while adding UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uidatepicker, uikeyboard

Is there any solution for making input view as transparent.Right now its giving dark background color.
Have already checked out other similar problem thread here and no solution yet.

Code:

```
`dateField=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,200, 200, 30)];
dateField.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
dateField.delegate=self;
dateField.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

UIDatePicker *calendar=[[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:[self.view bounds]];
calendar.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;
[calendar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[calendar addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
dateField.inputView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];dateField.inputView=calendar;
```

`

Comment: please add your code, so we can help.

Comment: added code for reference.